# Inconsistent results in ST_Distance

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have been playing with the `ST_Distance` function available within PostGIS and to my surprise, I have encountered some rather strange behavior...

In the simplest setting, I have just two tables `N` and `P`. Table `N` contains point coordinates, while table `P` contains multipolygons representing administrative divisions. Now, I would like to calculate the distance between a particular node and given range of (multi)polygons. To this end, I just invoked following command:

```
demo=> SELECT N.node_id, P.iid, ST_Distance(P.outline::geography, N.location::geography, false)
       FROM N, P WHERE (N.node_id=9 AND P.iid=25);

  node_id |  iid  |   st_distance
 ---------+-------+------------------
        9 |    25 | 1732718.95934996
 (1 row)
```

which seems to produce the expected result.
However, if I slightly modify the `WHERE` condition:

```
demo=> SELECT N.node_id, P.iid, ST_Distance(P.outline::geography, N.location::geography, false)
       FROM N, P WHERE (N.node_id=9 AND P.iid>=20 AND P.iid<=25);
 node_id |  iid  |   st_distance
---------+-------+------------------
       9 |    20 | 1738836.97788419
       9 |    21 | 1723001.48856517
       9 |    22 | 1736600.89344563
       9 |    23 | 1718786.25166805
       9 |    24 | 1503840.93486047
       9 |    25 |                0
(6 rows)
```

the result for pair `9, 25` suddenly changes. Am I missing something obvious? I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.5 (Postgis 2.1.8) on CentOS 7.

**EDIT:**

It seems that the problem persists even if I test only the "suspicious" polygon versus several points, i.e., let's consider only following points

```
 node_id |       st_astext        
---------+------------------------
       8 | POINT(-3.9018 42.8116)
       9 | POINT(-6.1947 41.5758)
      10 | POINT(-6.0858 41.4912)
```

and only polygon 25 (http://pastebin.com/7deJPC3u). Then I get:

```
demo=> SELECT N.node_id, P.iid, ST_Distance(P.outline::geography, N.location::geography, false)
       FROM N, P WHERE (N.node_id IN (9) AND P.iid=25);
 node_id |  iid  |   st_distance    
---------+-------+------------------
       9 |    25 | 1732718.95934996
(1 row)
```

as well as:

```
demo=> SELECT N.node_id, P.iid, ST_Distance(P.outline::geography, N.location::geography, false)
       FROM N, P WHERE (N.node_id IN (8,9,10) AND P.iid=25);
 node_id |  iid  |   st_distance    
---------+-------+------------------
       8 |    25 | 1731869.60412558
       9 |    25 |                0
      10 |    25 | 1729708.79737747
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This looks odd. Would you be able to share the geometries with us for testing?

Comment: I included the point coordinates as well as the "affected" polygon. I did similar calculations with several other polygons (around 10000), but it seems that this happens only in this particular case...

Comment: A vague proposition: what if you use ST_ForceRHR (http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForceRHR.html) at first!?

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the tip - however, it seems that the problem persits. Although replacing `ST_Distance(P.outline::geography, N.location::geography)` with `ST_Distance(P.outline, N.location)` yields a non-zero result which is not affected by the `WHERE` condition...

Comment: @Stefan Interestingly, it works with `ST_Reverse`! i.e, `ST_Distance(ST_Reverse(P.outline)::geography, N.location::geography)` gives consistent result while `ST_Distance(ST_ForceRHR(P.outline)::geography, N.location::geography)` keeps producing the mysterious zero...

Comment: @ewcz Yes, indeed! Maybe check your geometries. There is the function `ST_IsValidDetail` to check if a geometry is well formed. `ST_MakeValid` makes an invalid geometry valid. PostGIS 2.1 compiled with SFCGAL has a `ST_ForceLHR` function.

Comment: Besides, what is `max(P.iid)`?

Comment: @Stefan `SELECT valid(ST_IsValidDetail(P.outline)) FROM P WHERE P.iid=25;` returns `t`. The table `P` contains around 8000 multi-polygons.

Comment: What PostGIS version are you running? This looks like a disagreement between the cached tree-based distance algorithm and the brute force algorithm. There were a number of such issues in 2.1 that got fixed over time in patch releases. Using the latest patch release would be recommendation #1.

Comment: @PaulRamsey thanks for the suggestion. I tried again with a clean install (in a virtual machine in order to eliminate any side-effects) of PostgreSQL 9.5.0 and `POSTGIS="2.2.1 r14555" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" SFCGAL="1.2.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11" TOPOLOGY RASTER"` but the problem sadly prevails...

Comment: OK, you can confirm that the algorithms differ by comparing the results of `_ST_DistanceUnCached(geog,geog)` to `_ST_DistanceTree(geog,geog)` for your one suspect pairing. If they do in fact differ, please put the pairing into a postgis ticket: you have found a bug.

Comment: @PaulRamsey many thanks, indeed, it does differ, `_ST_DistanceUnCached` yields the expected result while `_ST_DistanceTree` does not

Comment: Damn. Well, looking forward to the ticket.

Comment: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3448 (sample geometries are included)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can confirm that the discrepancy is a bug by comparing the results of `_ST_DistanceUnCached(geog,geog)` to `_ST_DistanceTree(geog,geog)`

What is happening under the covers is that the "tree" algorithm only kicks in when a geometry shows up in a query a couple times in a row. At that point the geometry is cached and a tree built on it, for faster distance calculation. This can result in the odd results seen above, where the order in which geometries hit the function can change the results. When the bad pairing of geometries hit the function first, the brute-force, uncached algorithm was used. When it hit later, the tree algorithm was used.